# how to create an autocomplete textbox which procedure possessed three parameters, namely the textbox / parameter field, select query, and connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to create an autocomplete textbox which procedure possessed three parameters, namely the textbox / parameter field, select query, and connection?
so far I am using ajax auto complete, but the parameter field (prefixText) it can not be replaced..

```
enter code here public static List<string> GetNama(string prefixText)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from report where nama like @nama+'%' or report_id like @report_id+'%'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", prefixText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_id", prefixText);

    List<string> ReportNama = new List<string>();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            ReportNama.Add(sdr[0].ToString());
            ReportNama.Add(sdr[1].ToString());
        }
    }
    return ReportNama;
}
```

how to make auto complete text as I was getting on?
do not use ajax auto complete does not matter.. 
thanks if you can help me Smile | :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the following link:
http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-autocomplete-extender-using-asp-net-4-0-and-c/